# How do I use a TPL TransformBlock when waiting for multiple inputs?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

If I have multiple sources of data (say from a database) and then perform some CPU bound work how do I represent this using TPL DataFlow?

I've noticed the TransformBlock takes one input source, but the input comes from multiple sources and I want to make most of parallelism to achieve this.

Is the best way to use regular TPL or Parallel extensions to perform the IO bound work to the database and then merge this data into one point for the TransformBlock?

Comment: I believe you can simply link multiple blocks into your transform block. The part that does the management of flow is the level of concurrency you configure the block to have. This assumes all of your data-producing database "blocks" are supplying the same data type, as `TransformBlock` has a `TInput` and `TOutput`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) and find the sections `Specifying the Degree of Parallelism` and `Specifying the Number of Messages per Task`.

Comment: Thanks, the **TInput** would be a container class containing multiple child classes/collections which are eventually populated via lots of database calls.  I want all the nested child classes to be populated using TPL rather than in a synchronous fashion.  Maybe my question should be how do I create a Buffered source block which takes many inputs and ONLY when all inputs have been received is it passed to the transform block as a whole unit?

Comment: So there is also a `BufferBlock` but I think it doesn't wait on a per-source basis. You might want to look at the `Join` block, which then passes on a `Tuple` of results, it's all in that link, scroll up from the sections I mentioned previously for an overview of the built-in blocks.

Comment: What exactly does "multiple sources of data" mean? Are the sources interchangeable? Or do you need to combine the data that's coming from the sources somehow? Without knowing that, I think this is impossible to answer.

Comment: As an example, imagine a Customer header record with an orders collection and perhaps a wishlist coming from a SQL database. I want to retrieve those 3 separate pieces of data and merge into one class which will be serialized.  I'd like to merge via TPL DataFlow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [JoinBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228610(v=vs.110).aspx), it might be what you need.

You can also create a [Custom Dataflow Block Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228606(v=vs.110).aspx), that can do what you want to achieve.

For example, if you are expecting 5 objects to arrive, before you "process" them, and return a single object (I use expando here to illusrate...) , to a single receiver (that should also asynchronously await):

```
public sealed class YourCustomBlock : IPropagatorBlock<ExpandoObject, ExpandoObject>
{

    // The target part of the block. coming in
    private readonly ITargetBlock<ExpandoObject> m_target;
    // The source part of the block. going out
    private readonly ISourceBlock<ExpandoObject> m_source;
    // dependency count
    private readonly int _size ;

    // temporary holding area of incoming stuff
    private Queue<ExpandoObject> _queue;

    public YourCustomBlock(int inputs)
    {
      _size = inputs;
      _queue = new Queue<ExpandoObject>(_size);

      var mainWorker= new TransformBlock<ExpandoObject[], ExpandoObject>     (async expandoArray =>
        {
            // Do Your Stuff with expandoArray and then return something
            // ExpandoObject in this example

            await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false); 

            return /*Some ExpandoObject */;
        });

        var head = new ActionBlock<ExpandoObject>(async item =>
        {

            _queue.Enqueue(item);

            if (_queue.Count > _size)
            {
                _queue.Dequeue();  
            }
            // Post when you reach
            // the size
            if (_queue.Count == _size)
            {
                await mainWorker.SendAsync(_queue.ToArray());
                _queue.Clear();
            }
        });

        // expose as a block
        m_source = mainWorker;
        m_target = head;

    }
}
```

Sample use:

```
var myBlock = new YourCustomBlock(5);
Task.Run(async () => {
 for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
    await myBlock.SendAsync(/*SomeExpandoObject*/).ConfigureAwait(false);
 }
});

var results = await myBlock.ReceiveAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**Note: This has not been compile checked, and is just an illustration of the idea.**

Comment: Thanks for so much for the effort in writing this answer, sorry I hadn't marked it as answered.  Again my apologies.